# Initialize schema for in-memory database?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, in-memory-database

using latest Spring boot as of time of this writing 3.0.2.
Cannot seem to start in memory database with SpringBatch.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION E where JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ? and JOB_EXECUTION_ID in (SELECT max(JOB_EXECUTION_ID) from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION E2 where E2.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ?) [42104-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
```

I have this in my yaml:

```
server:
  port: 8091
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:job-db
    username: sa
    password: password
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      show-sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  integration:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: embedded
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
    job:
      enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was that I placed `@EnableBatchProcessing` in config class. I think this was required with prior versions of Boot.

Comment: yes, and this is mentioned in the migration guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes